# How to work with SRI hash and "onload" attribute

Tags: attributes, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

Following Google Lighthouse recommandations to get a faster response for my website, I'm using this trick to post-load fonts:

```
<link as="style"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700&amp;display=swap"
  onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"
  rel="preload">
```

But it fails because of my strict CSP rules, and I don't know how to add a sha384 hash for this "onload" attribute :/

I tried to get the `onload` content hash like this:

```
echo "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" | openssl dgst | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

Output: `npWtxZLLH7z2/zORM47igyJ5eTYuOl9qxzn4A632S7yMmMKBDHhL5ZHC6eBSxc/C`

Then I add it on CSP SRI list, and refresh, but it fails with:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'strict-dynamic' '[...list of other SRI hashes...]'
> sha384-npWtxZLLH7z2/zORM47igyJ5eTYuOl9qxzn4A632S7yMmMKBDHhL5ZHC6eBSxc/C
> 'unsafe-inline' http: https:". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if
> either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

How to permit this inline "onload" little script without authorize all inline scripts ?
Why my SRI doesn't work when I add it ? :(

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why my SRI doesn't work when I add it ? :(

It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934589/csp-header-fails-with-refused-to-apply-inline-style-but-i-have-already-adde/63974460#63974460) on example of *style-src* directive. With the *script-src* situation the same.

> How to permit this inline "onload" little script without authorize all
> inline scripts ?

Move inline event handler of 'load' to a separate script like 'click' in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63832626/why-cant-i-get-around-my-csp-blocking-my-javascript-code-in-nunjucks-when-i-use/63982215#63982215). Then it can be allowed by 'nonce-value' or 'sha256/sha384/sha512-value'.

**Updated:**

I wish to clarity changes to do (move inline handler to a separate script):

```
<link as="style" id="fonts"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700&amp;display=swap"
  rel="preload">

<script nonce="sever_generated_value"> // if 'nonce-value' used.
  // Or just calculate hash sha256 (or sha384/512) of this script
  // and insert it into 'script-src' as 'sha256-calculated_value' 
  fonts.addEventListener("load", function() {
     this.onload=null;
     this.rel='stylesheet';
     });
</script>
```

Such separate inline script can be allowed by 'nonce-value'/'hash-value'.

PS: Pls note that Content Security Policy does not support 'hash-value' via SRI for **external** style sheets. Is supported only for built-in `<style>...</style>`. For scripts the 'hash-value' [is supported for both](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash): buil-in `<script>...</script>` and external `<script src='...' integrity='hash_here'>`

Comment: Okay thanks ; I think it makes sense, following the current SRI draft. The main "resource" is the style fetched and not the attribute's content. But, even the official draft says it works with <script> and <link> while it works with <style> too :/

Comment: I has expanded my answer a little bit to avoid misunderstanding or misleading. SRI works separately and independently from CSP, but but CSP could use *integrity=* attribute to allow `<script src=>` via *'hash-nonce'*. `<link href=` is not supported by CSP, but could work for SRI check.